# SharePoint Online Master page changes for all site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page

I did master page changes to SharePoint Online using SharePoint Designer for one site collection.

How can I implement it for all site collection and newly created site collection , without modifying each site collection master page globally.

Comment: Which one you have customized? `.master` or `.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set it globally but what you can

1. Download your master page
2. Download all design files like css & js

Now upload everything in your new site collection and also publish.

**PS:** as your environment is SPO, you can utilize [Designer Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822363.aspx).